# NextJS 13 Route-Specific CSS Stylesheets Loading Improperly

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, next.js, next.js13

We're having trouble with our route-specific CSS stylesheets in our NextJS 13 application. When transitioning between routes (e.g., `/auth` to `/home`), the CSS stylesheets from the previous route load concurrently with the current route's stylesheets, leading to styling issues.

As a workaround, we've been reloading the page every time a user visits, which correctly loads the CSS. We thought this could be due to us defining components with string classnames and also by setting the CSS filename without the `.module.css` (e.g., "styles.css" as opposed to "styles.module.css") (`<div className="someclass" >...</div>`), as opposed to using the `.module.css` format (`<div className={styles.someclass}>...</div>`). However, changing all components to use the latter approach caused all our styles to not apply at all.

We wished we had the scoping of styles to single components like in Svelte and wish to achieve something similar in React. Any suggestions for addressing this problem, or identifying its root cause, would be greatly appreciated.